# Fixing bottom navigation bar + fixing link to another webpage

Tags: html, css

I'd like to ask your help with my bottom navigation bar and a link on both my navigation bars.

I can't seem to make it appear in the center. Will using padding be able to fix it? I've been trying to use it, but I have to estimate the number of pixels.

My second problem is that my bottom navigation bar doesn't have the correct spacing. I already changed the font size, but it doesn't fix the problem. Right now, it appears like this: "HomeWho We AreWhat We Do...".

My third problem is that one of my links don't appear to be working. It's a link to another webpage I coded. I think I've typed it correctly, but it won't work.

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/captainpokey/66szogpm/

And here's the code:

```css
html {
 100%
}

body {
 background: #cecdcc;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #8c8b8a;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

#wrap {
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 45px;
 background: #dcdbda;
 font-family: "Lato";
 font-size: 18px;
}

#nav ul {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: #dcdbda;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 50px; 
}
 
#nav li {
 height: 40px;
 padding-top: 4px;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 width: 150px;
 list-style: none;
}
 
#nav a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 color: #949392;
}

#nav ul ul {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 100%;
 visibility: hidden;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
  
#nav li:hover, #nav li:hover li {
 background: #fff;
}

#nav li li:hover, #nav li li:hover li {
 background: #bbb;
}
 
#nav li:hover  ul {
 visibility: visible;
}

#header {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 485px;
 background-image: url(../images/headerphoto.jpg);
}

#content {
 background-color: #fff;
 font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
 color: #777674;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#content h4 {
 padding-left: 150px;
 padding-right: 150px;
 font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-transform: bold;
}

#content p {
 padding-left: 150px;
 padding-right: 150px;
 font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-transform: bold;
}

#footer {
 background-image: url(../images/footerphoto.jpg);
 width: 1000px;
 height: 255px;
}

#navbottom {
 padding-left: 130px;
 width: 1000px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-family: "Lato";
}

#navbottom ul {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

#navbottom ul li {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 list-style-type: none;
}

#navbottom li:hover ul {
 visibility: visible;
}

#navbottom a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
}

#copyright {
 padding-left: 150px;
 padding-right: 150px;
 font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>Powers & Grant, Inc.</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
 <div id="wrap">
  <div id="nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="whoweare.html">Who We Are</a></li> 
   <li><a href="whatwedo.html">What We Do</a></li>
   <li><a href="ourservices.html">Our Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="thepowersteam.html">The Powers Team</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div id="header"></div>
  
  <div id="content">
  <p>As the Country&#39;s pioneer in sales force outsourcing, Powers knows the intricacies of managing the critical tasks involved in increasing revenues as well as saving the company from the costly maintenance of agents with minimal increase in sales growth.<br><br>

Powers and Grant Inc. currently handles and manages sales teams for various industries principally involved in the Real Estate, Consumer, and 
Pharmaceutical and Direct Selling companies.<br><br>

We assist companies in enhancing their competitiveness through application of competencies and integrate these essential factors needed to survive 
today&#39;s need for continued innovation.<br><br></p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="footer">
  
  <div id="navbottom">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="whoweare.html">Who We Are</a></li> 
   <li><a href="whatwedo.html">What We Do</a></li>
   <li><a href="ourservices.html">Our Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="thepowersteam.html">The Powers Team</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div><br>
  
  <div id="copyright">Copyright &copy; Powers and Grant, Inc. All Rights Reserved</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Please help! Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the changes here.

https://jsfiddle.net/66szogpm/1/

code to align your top nav text to center

```
#nav li {
    line-height: 40px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

code to align your bottom nav

```
#navbottom {
    padding-left: 100px;
    width: 1000px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Lato";
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#navbottom ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#navbottom ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 5px 10px;
}
```

You have used float: left in many places, which isn't necessary. All you had to do was change the display property to inline-block.

I haven't changed it for the top nav. But, you can try it out.

Comment: inline-block means placing elements next to each other. The elements flow to the next line if there isn't enough space to fit them all in a single line.